# C# Entity Framework. Не работает добавление записи в БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте всем.

Использую Model First подход. Есть две сущности: Catalog и Book. Отношение между ними один-ко-многим. После создании модели сформировал автоматически классы для Catalog и Book:

```
namespace Library
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Catalog
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Catalog()
        {
            this.Books = new HashSet<Book>();
        }

        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace Library
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Book
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Book()
        {
            this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }

        public virtual Catalog Catalog { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Класс контекста так выглядит:

```
namespace Library
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class LibraryModelContainer : DbContext
    {
        public LibraryModelContainer()
            : base("name=LibraryModelContainer")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Catalog> Catalogs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Далее я хочу осуществить добавление записей в таблицы БД для Catalog и Book. Делаю таким образом:

```
private void AddUpdateRecord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (LibraryModelContainer dbContainer = new LibraryModelContainer())
    {
        Catalog catalog = new Catalog
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = CatalogTextBox.Text
        };

        dbContainer.Catalogs.Add(catalog);
        dbContainer.SaveChanges();
        _window.CatalogDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbContainer.Catalogs.ToList();
    }
}


private void AddUpdateRecord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (LibraryModelContainer dbContainer = new LibraryModelContainer())
    {
            Book book = new Book
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = BookAuthorTextBox.Text,
                Genre = BookGenreComboBox.Text,
                Author = BookAuthorTextBox.Text,
                Year = BookYearTextBox.Text,
                Catalog = (Catalog) BookCatalogComboBox.SelectedItem,
            };

            dbContainer.Books.Add(book);
            dbContainer.SaveChanges();
            _window.BookDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbContainer.Books.ToList();
    }
}
```

При добавлении записи в таблицу Catalog, у меня проблем не возникает, поскольку всё понятно, как это делается. Когда же я хочу добавить книгу в таблицу Book, то здесь (dbContainer.SaveChanges();) возникает исключение:

1) UpdateException: При обновлении записей возникла ошибка. Дополнительные сведения приведены во внутреннем исключении.
2) SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Catalogs'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Catalogs'. The duplicate key value is (aea5ebab-5453-449e-b181-7bee12ce7a3c).
The statement has been terminated.

Что я конкретно делаю не так при добавлении записи в таблицу Book?

Comment: `Catalog = (Catalog) BookCatalogComboBox.SelectedItem,` так нельзя. Вы извлекаете выбранный каталог, определяете его Id, или др. отлич. признак, потом обращаетесь к базе ищете такой каталог по базе, если находите, то потом уже присваиваете это найденное значение нужной книге и потом уже пытаетесь ее сохранить. Как-то так.

Comment: А как тогда нужно правильно делать? Я сделал так, как здесь описано, даже не смотря на то, что там используется Windows Forms: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.3.php

Comment: Я уже написал как надо. Читайте внимательнее.

Comment: Я это всё прочитал, я ничего не понял из того, что вы написали. Вы можете, пожалуйста, показать, как это выглядит?

Comment: Вы поймите, что когда вы оборачиваете LibraryModelContainer в using, то у вас при выходе из этого блока контекст уничтожается и не происходит работа по отслеживанию изменений в контексте, которую в принципе производит EF. Из-за такой работы у вас контекст считает, что выбранное в комбобоксе значение каталога новое и после присвоения свойству книги, он его, это значение каталога пытается записать в базу тоже, и потому вылезает конфликт с  key value is (aea5ebab-5453-449e-b181-7bee12ce7a3c).

Comment: Потому вам надо либо отказаться от using, либо перед назначением свойству Catalog книги, сделать поиск по базе этого каталога заново и найденное значение уже присвоить свойству Catalog книги и потом уже сохранять книгу. Ферштейн?

Comment: Странно, но получилось. https://ibb.co/eAHB37 — перед созданием объекта Book добавил строчку одну и всё ок. Я всё равно кое-что не понимаю.

Ваша цитата: "когда вы оборачиваете LibraryModelContainer в using, то у вас при выходе из этого блока контекст уничтожается и не происходит работа по отслеживанию изменений в контексте" . Когда именно это происходит? У меня же все действия находятся внутри конструкции using.

Ваша цитата: "Потому вам надо либо отказаться от using". Та же ошибка появляется в виде дубликата Id, если я убираю эту конструкцию. Или что имелось в виду под этими словами?

Comment: И самое непонятное для меня ещё то, что в чём разница между — `Catalog catalog = dbContainer.Catalogs.Find(((Catalog)BookCatalogComboBox.SelectedItem).Id);` и этим — `Catalog = (Catalog)BookCatalogComboBox.SelectedItem` (это свойство объекта Book, если что)??? Один и тот же результат будет в виде объекта класса Catalog. Просто я к тому, а что будет, если пользователь при добавлении книги не укажет каталог? Это вполне реальная ситуация. Ну очевидно, что будет null при создании объекта Book. Тогда какой смысл делать поиск каталога по Id до создания объекта Book?

Comment: Сразу прошу прощения за столько многочисленное количество вопросов к вам, поскольку я много чего не знаю и не понимаю в данный момент, к сожалению.